# ¿Por qué recibo el mensaje "$'echo\241Hola': command not found"?

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer scripts en linux pero no consigo usar variables:

```
saludo="Hola mundo"
echo $saludo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
root@debian-9:/home/vagrant# ./hola.sh
./hola.sh: line2: $'echo\241Hola': command not found
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes tener algún carácter extraño, si no no tiene sentido el error. Iría bien que copiaras el texto tal cual, pues lo mismo usas un `$` diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola debes de utilizar comillas

```
echo "${saludo}"
```